# how to make a underline on every page

Tags: html, css

I already got an underline hover when you go over it.
but now I try to find out how I can make an underline, for example I go to my ''about'' page
so I want an underline under about, so they know I am on that page and when I go to another page like home you will see there is an underline.
sorry for my bad English, hope you guys understand me

html code

Comment: text-decoration:underline;

Comment: Do you have a navigation bar where all of your page links are displayed? Or where are the items, that you want to underline? Can you maybe add these information to your question?

Comment: Static or dynamic pages?

Comment: @OttherCreek i got a navigation bar where i got the pages linked but its one website scrolled down

Comment: @RezaSaadati static

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to make underline for active pages,

```
.activepage a:active{
text-decoration:underline;
text-decoration-color: blue;
border: none;
display: block;
position: relative;
opacity: 0.8;
color: #1a1a1a;
}
```

Here I have taken class named `activepage` and `a` is link within it.
so whenever user will be on activepage underline will be shown.

Thanks..